# PowerShell function result wont be send via Email

Tags: email, powershell

I'm using this PowerShell function to check on a folder.
it works fine and when adding, changing and deleting a file happens on the folder; it shows the log message on the host screen.

```
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher | Get-Member -Type Properties,Event 
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = "C:\Users\ali.shariaty\Desktop\test"
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Created  -Action {
  $Object  = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
  $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
  $Event.TimeGenerated
  $WriteHostParams  = @{
  ForegroundColor = 'Green'
  BackgroundColor =  'Black'
  Object =  $Object
  }
  Write-Host @WriteHostParams
} 
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Changed  -Action {
  $Object  = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
  $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
  $Event.TimeGenerated
  $WriteHostParams  = @{
  ForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
  BackgroundColor =  'Black'
  Object =  $Object
  }
  Write-Host @WriteHostParams
} 
  Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher  -EventName Deleted  -Action {
  $Object  = "{0} was  {1} at {2}" -f $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath,
  $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType,
  $Event.TimeGenerated
  $WriteHostParams  = @{
  ForegroundColor = 'Red'
  BackgroundColor =  'Black'
  Object =  $Object
  }
  Write-Host @WriteHostParams
}
```

My issue is when I add these lines to my code to send me the result by email, the body of my emails are empty and do not contain the log message.

```
$mailtxt = $WriteHostParams
$mailSmtpServer = "mail.domain.com";
$mailFrom = "ali.shariaty@domain.com";
$mailTo = "ali.shariaty@domain.com";
$mailSubject = "Folder Change"
$mailbody = $mailtxt
$mail = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($mailSmtpServer);
$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
$msg.IsBodyHtml = 1;
$msg.To.Add($mailTo);
$msg.From = $mailFrom;
$msg.Subject = $mailSubject;
$msg.Body = $mailbody;
$mail.Send($msg);
```

Can someone help and tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the body to just the message? i.e.

```
$mailtext = $WriteHostParams.Object
```

Currently you are trying to set the body of the email to a hashtable, which I would expect would just set it to "System.Collections.Hashtable" after it was casted to a string